# Android studio debug:Frame is not available

Tags: android

when I debug my app on a real device,I got this problem. At the very first ,the debugger perform well and i can do some basic debug operations,but after a moment (approximately 2-5 seconds) the debugger just stopped and show me that "Frame is not available",i just put one break point in my code,and i have been searched an explanation for a long time,but it seems nothing work,so if you could provide some suggestions,i will be very thankful!

Comment: check your usb cable

Comment: there is no problem with the cable,and there is a NullPointerException in my code, i set the break point to find out where it is

Answer (score -1):

This will happen when the connection between debug port and device is lost.

1. If your cable is loose then the connection will be lost. It's a basic tcp connection
2. If your code have some crash then also the connection will be lost.

So you have to check is there any error, if you believe your code is absolutly perfect

Thanks

Comment: Yes,there is a NullPointerException in my code ,and i set the break point to find out where it is. Is that the reason my debugger crashed when the code's execution  reachs the exception?

Comment: You can find out the null pointer from stacktrace in android logcat. put break point before that code.

Comment: there is a log i dismissed,Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket',what does it mean?

Comment: Actually when you click debug app, our pc will create a tcp connection on port 8600 fro android studio and phone will connect to this port. and the communication is happened with this connection. That is why if you got any crash the VM(Virtual machine) will stop then the connection will dropfrom socket

Comment: I think i have got the key, the break point was set at main thread,and before the break point i send a broadcast in my code, as we all know that the broadcast receiver done its business at the main thread ,thus if the application stopped at the main thread ,it will result in ANR if the broadcast has not been dealt with within ten seconds,that's where the problem is. So as you say,there is a problem in the source code. Last but not least,thanks for your patience,and i have voted for your answer,but you can't see it as my reputation is lower than 15.  Can we two become friends?

Comment: Yeh of course. And one thing , If  broadcast was not dealt within 10 sec it will automatically dismiss.

Comment: what is your facebook acount?